# pennylane:fidelity calculation after swap test between entagled states. Swap test issue

Tags: entanglement, fidelity, pennylane, swap-test

What I am trying to do is first take an image and encode it into quantum states, for this I have taken an image from the MNIST dataset and then reshaped it to (4,4) and now I wrote the following circuit to prepare quantum states for it.

```
dev=qml.device("default.qubit",wires=4)
@qml.qnode(dev)

def quantum_encoding(image,params):
  qml.AmplitudeEmbedding(image,wires=range(4),normalize=True)

  for i in range(4):

    qml.Hadamard(wires=i)
    qml.RX(params[i],wires=i)
   
  qml.CNOT(wires=[0,1])
  qml.CNOT(wires=[1,2])
  qml.CNOT(wires=[2,3])

  return qml.state()
```

Now I wanted to create  a function that could take in two quantum states and then perform a swap test between them and return fidelity. So I tried it in the following manner.

```
@qml.qnode(dev2)
def swap(state1,state2):

  qml.QubitStateVector(state1,wires=[4,5,6,7])
  qml.QubitStateVector(state2,wires=[8,9,10,11])

 
  ancillea=[]
  for i in range(4):
    anc=i
    ancillea.append(anc)
    first_state=i+4
    second_state=i+8
    qml.CSWAP(wires=[anc,first_state,second_state])


  return qml.state()
```

An issue i faced  was that I got this error -

DeviceError: Operation QubitStateVector cannot be used after other Operations have already been applied on a default.qubit.autograd device.

As the output of the first function quantum_encoding is an 16 bit number or maybe like a 4qubit state ,

first I would like to know if my attempt to perform swap test between the two quantum encoded states is correct or not?

second I would like to know how to perform fidelity calculations with this and how to avoid the error?

Answer (score 3):

As the error suggests, you cannot use `QubitStateVector` twice in the same QNode. Take, for instance, this simpler example that reproduces your error. Here, I want to initialize qubit 1 and 2 in a zero state:

```python
import pennylane as qml
from pennylane import numpy as np

dev=qml.device("default.qubit",wires=2)

@qml.qnode(dev)
def circuit(state1, state2):
    qml.QubitStateVector(state1, wires=0)
    qml.QubitStateVector(state2, wires=1)

    return qml.state()

state1 = np.array([1,0])
state2 = np.array([1,0])

print(circuit(state1, state2))

# DeviceError: Operation QubitStateVector cannot be used after other Operations have already been applied on a default.qubit.autograd device.
```

What you must do is take the kronecker/tensor product between the separate states and feed that into one instance of `QubitStateVector`. In this case, the tensor product of both zero states is simply `[1,0,0,0]`:

```python
@qml.qnode(dev)
def circuit(state):
    qml.QubitStateVector(state, wires=range(2))
    return qml.state()

state = np.array([1,0,0,0])

print(circuit(state))

# [1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
```

That said, this might be a cool feature to have in PennyLane (i.e., being able to use `QubitStateVector` more than once in one QNode provided that the wires don't overlap). Maybe you can make a feature request, or even [contribute to PennyLane](https://github.com/PennyLaneAI/pennylane#contributing-to-pennylane) yourself!

Comment: yea that works .But my goal is to find the fidelity between the two states obtained after performing SWAP test between the quantum states of the encoded image and hence I wanted to like try if I could get the density matrices of the 4 states (the one's on the 4 ancillary qubits) and then concatenate first two which would correspond to image_1 and then the other 2 correspond to image_2 and then I thought of using qml.math.fidelity between the two density matrices, but now I get the error,The state or density matrix cannot be returned in combination with other return types ,any workaround for it

Comment: Sorry,but I am kinda new to pennylane and quantum computing.

What I have tried is,I did what you told,i found the kronecker product between the state1 and state2 and made modifications as you suggested, and I returned a density matrix on the 4 ancillary qubits. The output of this was a 16,16 shaped array. We will call this array as density_matrix.

Now to this array i used qml.expval(qml.Hermitian(density_matrix,wires=[0,1,2,3])

this gave me my fidelity, I would like to know if this method is correct if not could you correct me and provide with a sample code if possible

Comment: No worries at all for being new to PennyLane @Pratyush! We all have to start from ground zero. You should be able to calculate the fidelity between two density matrices with [qml.math.fidelity](https://docs.pennylane.ai/en/stable/code/api/pennylane.math.fidelity.html?highlight=fidelity). There are some examples in that link. I think the error you were getting is stemming from you wanting to return multiple things from a QNode that cannot be returned simultaneously.